# Precise positioning and dimensioning using DaVinci Resolve

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve

I have some clips at different resolutions I want to put on my timeline (configured at 1920 x 1080), precisely at 2 pixels from the left, 2 pixels from the bottom, each clip being supposed to be resized to 1280 x 720.

Is there a way to (easily) do this on DaVinci Resolve (free version), without starting a bachelor of mathematics ?

Comment: Resolve does not work with pixels; it works resolution-independent. Maybe Handbrake is a better tool for that.

Comment: @U.Windl : ok, I understand that, but AFAIK videos are in pixels, and the need for a precise positioning at a given resolution is also there in the real world (no matter further upscales / downscales that can be done at export time). So I guess DaVinci Resolve is able to manage this "real world" needs in some (relative) easy way ?

Comment: Well the proportion of "1920/(1920-2)" is 960/959, or 1.001042752867... (or the other way around: 0.9989583...) To to move your FHD by 2 pixels, you can move it by 0.001042... in Resolve (I guess). Maybe it's really easier in Handbrake...